# Docker Swarm - Schedule container on each machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I'm currently trying to spawn a container instance of Redis separately on each cluster machine using Docker Swarm/Compose. I'm currently using 4 machines for the example. Using the affinity labels, the idea was to make sure two redis instances wouldn't get scheduled on to the same machine.

At first, the following worked.

```
redis:
  image: redis
  environment:
    AFFINITY: com.myself.name!=redis
  labels:
    - "com.myself.name=redis"
```

However after forcing some containers to stop to simulate crashes, pushing them back, turning all containers off, and then finally running everything from the start again using `docker-compose scale redis=4`, I find redis running two containers on the same machine even though there's 4 available in the cluster.

What exactly am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I think what might be happening is that once all the nodes get a container with that label, none of the nodes are valid, so it drops it as a constraint.  If you `docker ps -a` do you see all the nodes have a container ?  Note that even stopped containers are considered for these constraints, so you have to remove the containers to get it to work again. I'm working on improvements to the docs to call this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try this:

```
redis:
  image: redis
  environment:
    - "affinity:container!=*redis*"
  labels:
    - "com.myself.name=redis"
```

This should work!

Please, let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try this docker compose file

```
redis:
  image: redis
  environment:
    - affinity:com.myself.name!=redis
  labels:
    - "com.myself.name=redis"
```